# python - write formated file without fixed number of variables to print

Tags: python, format

I have these lines of code that create a list (with different amount of variables in it), and want to put them in an outfile. The thing is in

```
outfile.write('%i ?????' % (bn, crealines[bn]))
```

I don't know exactly how to write the format since the output varies in number.
Is there anyway of putting an output with different number of columns?

*I looked at this: [Increasing variables and numbers by one each time (python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16826545/increasing-variables-and-numbers-by-one-each-time-python) ... but in my case they don't increase one-by-one.
Also, can I print a list without the parenthesis?

The code is like this:

---

(# In this case I am creating a "cube" -matrix- of 3x3x3)

```
nx = ny = nz = 3
vec = []
crealines = []
outfile = open('test.txt', 'a')

for bn in arange(nx*ny*nz):
        vec = neighboringcubes(bn,nx,ny,nz) #this is a defined function to see which cubes are neighbors to the cube "bn"
        crealines.append(vec) 
        print bn, crealines[bn]
        outfile.write('%i, %i ....' % (bn, crealines[bn]))

outfile.close()
```

---

using print it gives me this (which is correct):

```
0 0 0  <---- this is the output from function neighboringcubes() -which I don't need-
0 [1, 3, 9] <---- THIS IS WHAT I WANT WRITTEN IN THE OUTPUTFILE

1 0 0
1 [2, 0, 4, 10]

2 0 0
2 [1, 5, 11]

0 1 0
3 [4, 6, 0, 12]

1 1 0
4 [5, 3, 7, 1, 13] <--- BUT YOU CAN SEE IT CHANGES

2 1 0
5 [4, 8, 2, 14]

0 2 0
6 [7, 3, 15]

1 2 0
7 [8, 6, 4, 16]

2 2 0
8 [7, 5, 17]

0 0 1
9 [10, 12, 18, 0]

1 0 1
10 [11, 9, 13, 19, 1]

...
```

---

I want the outfile to have in the first column the number of the cube, and the following columns -from lower to higher- the neighbors; like this:

```
0 1 3 9 
1 0 2 4 10
2 1 5 11
3 0 4 6 12
4 1 3 5 7 13  
5 2 4 8 14 
6 3 7 15 
7 4 6 8 16 
8 5 7 17
9  0 10 12 18
...
```

Comment: Can you clarify this question?  I feel that you mean to ask - "How do I print a sorted list of numbers"?

Comment: If I get your question correctly, you want to write into a file a list of changing length? Given that you separe your items with a space and your lists with a newline, why not simply use `" ".join(createlines)`?

Comment: @jaime that, but more important **to print a formated list that has no fixed number of elements**. See, some of the outputs have three items, other have five, then I don't know how many %i I need int he format line for print()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't quite clear to me, but I believe you want to print the variable `bn` followed by its neighbors in sorted order.  If so, this code snippet illustrates how to do that:

```
>>> bn = 5
>>> neighbors = [10, 12, 2, 4]
>>> print bn, ' '.join(map(str, sorted(neighbors)))
```

Which results in this output:

> 5 2 4 10 12

Comment: Thanks @jaime!

This solved the format problem: 

 print "{} {}".format(bn, ' '.join(map(str,crealines[bn])))


I sorted neighbors outside, then crealines[bn] is already sorted.

The output looks like this

5 2 4 8 14

Comment: Glad it fixed you, feel free to accept my answer :D

Comment: I had no idea you have to "accept" the answer given :D

Answer (score 1):

Few proposition, depending on what you exactly want (now they are the same, but may behave differently depending on data):

```
bn = 5
neighbours = [8, 12, -1, 4]
print "{} [{}]".format(bn, ', '.join(map(str, sorted(neighbours))))
print bn, repr(sorted(neighbours))
print bn, str(sorted(neighbours))
```

output:

```
5 [-1, 4, 8, 12]
5 [-1, 4, 8, 12]
5 [-1, 4, 8, 12]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the idea that you could just use `print bn, crealines[bn].sort()` but I could be wrong. (Thats because I cant test your code. Where is the function arange imported from?)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @jaime!

This solved the format problem:

print "{} {}".format(bn, ' '.join(map(str,crealines[bn])))

I sorted neighbors outside using vec=sorted(neighbors), then crealines[bn] is already sorted.

The output looks like this

5 2 4 8 14